# How can I parse a tfe_log to show what modules are being used?

Tags: terraform, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

My Org is exporting the Terraform Enterprise logs (tfe_log) into Splunk and I'm trying to create a visual dashboard to show what modules are being used, how often, and who downloaded it. The main problem I have is the lack of documentation on how the logs are formatted.

So far I have this, but it seems the count is still off when comparing it to the TFE module page.

```
index=automation sourcetype=tfe_log tfe-atlas oac modules registry datadog download GET earliest=-2mon 
| rex "registry\/(?<module>[a-z0-9-]+)-oac\/datadog\/[0-9.]+\/download" 
| stats count by module
```

Comment: An example of the tfe_log events would be helpful. Otherwise, you are expecting everyone else to just know what they are, or go do research.

Comment: Sorry @MadsHansen, I thought the TFE logs were standardized on format and info format coming in. If it's not, then I will work through it.. There is too much different info coming in to post here. Thank you..

Comment: `seems the count is still off` can you not get one those logs and see if your query gets the right count? ... if you have  Terraform Enterprise I expect you to have enterprise support you can contact for assistance with this

Comment: The issue I have is, the logs are providing more information then I want and it's hard to sort out without documentation. As for the TFE support, you are correct. The bad this is, I work at a very large company and TFE platform is run by another team. Thank you though.